# Is it valid inside a getter, call an action in vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

For example, I use a Getter for write a logic about a if object has a especify content.

```
    const state = {
       object = []
    }
    
    const getters = {
       CHECK_OBJECT_STATE: (state) => {
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(state.object, "error")){
                 //return a message, in this case is not necessary proceed the logic.
        }else{
          //otherwise I need take state.object.id and fetch a new a action.
//CALL ACTION FETCH_OBJECT_ID
        }
    } 
    
    }
    
    const actions = {
       FETCH_OBJECT(...){
       //SET MUTATION HERE
}
       FETCH_OBJECT_ID (..) {..}
    }
```

anyone can suggest me other method to do it, if it's not valid?

Answer (score 2):

Vuex Getters are not designed for asynchronous tasks, those should be handled in the `actions`. I really think that `getters` operate best as pure functions which perform read-only operations on an existing state, so it should do only one job: retrieve the data in the state.

So you process the logic, the `if` statement in the `actions`, store the returned value in a state array `object` (which is pretty weird for me to name an array "object"), and the `getter` only has to retrieve such array. Things are reactive so that `getter` will always hold the latest data set.